# mysqli_connect is killing php script when run from a web browser

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a php script does some computations then connects to a mysql database to write some data.  when i run the script from a terminal, the script runs fine.  when i run the script from a webpage (starts when i click a button in the page), the script dies once it hits the mysql_connect statement in the php code.

not sure what code or data to provide you folks to help with the debug...just dies with no error message. if anyone has suggestions on what additional data to post, please let me know.

could it be some kind of permissions issue?  for some reason at the terminal my account can access the mysqli libs containing the mysqli_connect functon, but the apache web user doesn't have those permissions?  i'm stuck...have never seen this before.

test.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
connectToDB();
print "hi manny";

function connectToDB() {
$hostname = "XXXXX";
$port = "XXX";
$schema = "XXXX";
$username = "XXXXX";
$password = "XXXXX";

print "got inside\n";
$dbh = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $schema, $port);
print "got connect\n";
// Check connection
if (!$dbh) {
    echo "connection failed\n";
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 echo "Connected successfully\n";
 return $dbh;
}
?>
```

when run from command line:

> [manoli@app01 site1]$ php -f test.php 
> got inside
> got connect
> Connected successfully
> hi manny
>
> when run from webpage via ajax:
> got inside
>
> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in >**/var/www/apps/site1/test.php** on line **16**

Comment: My guess would be you have PHP error reporting off and that's why there's no error message.

Comment: On what @Nordenheim said, turn error reporting on with `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and show us what pops up.

Comment: If there's no error, how do you know `mysql_connect` is the issue?

Comment: i had error_reporting on.  i added ini_set and now i see the following:

<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in <b>/var/www/apps/site1/handleRegistration.php</b> on line <b>80</b><br>
<br>
why would it not be able to find the mysqli_connect function when run from webpage, but it can from the command line? @darren

Comment: You need to supply the code so we can debug.

Comment: i just posted the code @Darren

Comment: @user3255120 There's a very high chance your PHP is compiled without MySQLi support. Try running `phpinfo();` and see if mysqli is there.

Comment: My guess is that you gave two different versions of PHP installed. The CLI one has mysqli then CGI one does not.

Comment: @user3255120: The PHP CLI (command line) and apache/CGI modules (or whatever webserver you're using) can have *different* php.ini files.  Same PHP version, just different configs.  So, it's possible mysqli is enabled for one, but not the other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli\_connect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719719/linux-php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-connect)

Comment: both the web and command line report php.ini as /etc/php.ini.  however, there are no references to mysqli in the web phpinfo, but tons of them in cli phpinfo.   sorry, not an expert on this...how would i go about remedying this? 

does this mean there are two versions of php on the server?

Comment: some more info...in additional .ini files parsed, web phpinfo shows only /etc/php.d/dbase.ini, but cli shows:
additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/dbase.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini

Comment: should apache httpd.conf file have a load module statement for mysql?  something like:

LoadModule ??? modules/mysqli.so

mine doesn't have any reference to mysqli

Comment: how can i tell if i have two versions of php installed and where they are located on disk?  the configure command options from webpage phpinfo() are very different from those for the CLI phpinfo. @robbmj

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have MySQLi enabled. You should check your `phpinfo()` for MySQLi support.